# Does the $\mathbb{F}_1$ point of view lead to any testable predictions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, field-with-one-element

In number theory we can informally consider number rings as curves over something like a field with one element. For example it is mentioned [here](https://kskedlaya.org/papers/aws-notes.pdf#page=133) by Kedlaya.

The question is does this perspective lead to any proper conjectures that could either be proved or refuted?

Comment: Alain Connes mentioned this point of view in 'An essay on the Riemann Hypothesis' (https://alainconnes.org/wp-content/uploads/EssayRH.pdf).

Comment: Is this really distinct from asking about the function field analogy as in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+field+analogy ?